# How to Combine WSO2 ES and WSO2 DS

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

1. How to Upload Gadget content to WSO2 ES
2. How to Download Gadget content to WSO2 DS from WSO2 ES

Answer (score 0):

Right now this feature is not available in WSO2 DS 2.0.0 which is to add external gadget stores. But currently development of this feature is in progress and will be available in 2.0.1 release. So adding gadgets to the DS is done manually through the file system. User can add the gadget to PRODUCT_HOME/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/portal/store/carbon.super/gadgets

Then user can use this gadget in dashboard creation.

And About uploading gadget content to the ES. In ES we only maintain the metadata of the artifacts(Ex:-gadgets). You can upload your gadget's whole content in to ES but only as an archive. But as we store the artifact in registry we recommend to content to be under size of 1MB. Also you can keep the gadget in your own location (Ex:-local file system).Then ES only manages the life-cycle of the artifact. After that you have to download the gadget and manually copy it in to DS. Also keep in mind not to update the gadget urls related to ES. Because ES cannot serve the gadget. You have to download the gadget.